# How to add splash screen in flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

**I want to show a splash screen like this**
[image]

Comment: which title bar do you want to avoid please be more specific

Comment: i don't want to show any bar it just has to be a window only shows like splash like the mentioned one has

Comment: If you don't include an `AppBar` in the scaffold, then there won't be one. Do you know how implement a Splash Screen in Flutter? Please update your question with more specifics.

Comment: i am not talking about in app AppBar i just want to do the task that is mentioned in the picture

Answer (score 2):

The Flutter team has not created any documentation regarding adding a splash screen on desktop.  You can upvote <s>[this ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82538)</s> [this ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41980) to show your support for adding this documentation.